# ondeviceready load everytime with submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I call the function "getallrecords()" in the onDeviceReadyto to load some data from the db. This function has to be executed once.
I have on an other page a form with a submit button. Problem is that everytime I submit the form the onDeviceReady will load again with that function. How can I load the function only once?

Form:

```
<form data-ajax="false" onsubmit="return adddata();"
```

onDeviceReady:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{ 
    getallrecords()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var recordsLoaded = false;

function onDeviceReady() 
{ 
    if (recordsLoaded === false) {
        getallrecords()
        recordsLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I think that a submit will load the whole page and set everytime the recordsLoaded on false